Spark Dataframes exploding columns into rows
Any helps on following would be greatly appreciated. It is related to normalizing a spark dataframe. Please find the input dataframe schema below,
Input dataframe schema: Actor, Movie_Name1, Movie_Director1, Movie_Budget_1, Movie_Collection_week1_1, Movie_collection_week2_1, Movie_Name2, Movie_Director2, Movie_Budget_2, Movie_Collection_week1_2, Movie_collection_week2_2.
I want the output dataframe with below schema,
Output dataframe schema: Actor, Movie_ID, Movie_Name, Movie_Director, Movie_Budget, Movie_Collection_week1, Movie_collection_week2.
How do I achieve this?
Main reason that I am doing this is - It is leading to create more than 1000 columns at some point and it is causing GC allocation issue in databricks along with below issues.
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 129667863K->1553780K(131095040K)] 139430933K->11316858K(401177088K), 0.0990031 secs] [Times: user=3.85 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs] 

Photon BufferPool exceeded its static memory reservation by 514.0 MiB. The BufferPool reservation is 128.0 MiB, and can be controlled by
spark.databricks.photon.bufferPoolReservationSize. Exceeding the reservation may lead to the process being OS OOM-killed.

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=242569Kb max_used=242626Kb free=3190Kb
bounds [0x00007f45dd000000, 0x00007f45ec000000, 0x00007f45ec000000]
total_blobs=45029 nmethods=43539 adapters=1391
compilation: disabled (not enough contiguous free space left)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=




Can you add an example of the data?

Added screenshot of sample

can you please show/tell the discriminating factor? are they always the same name or are those columns incremental like Movie_Budget_1.2.3.... ?

Those columns are incremental. that's where the major issue is ... some times it increases up to 100 movies which makes it much harder to process the data with that many columns.

even with hundred movies, will the columns be only 2 or that also will change - e.g. will all movies have only 2 weekly columns or is that dynamic as well ? Movie_Collection_week1_1, Movie_Collection_week1_2
